# Recursive mkdir() and chmod()?

Tags: php, permissions, chmod, mkdir

When using [**`mkdir()`**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mkdir.php) with the recursive flag set to true do all the created directories get the specified chmod or just the last one? For example:

```
mkdir('/doesnotExist1/doesnotExist2/doesnotExist3/', 0755, true);
```

Will the newly created directories `/doesnotExist1/` and `/doesnotExist1/doesnotExist2/` also get the same chmod as `/doesnotExist1/doesnotExist2/doesnotExist3/` = 0755?

If not, is there any way to **force the above behavior**?

I would test this myself, but I don't have access to a *nix box ATM.

Comment: Surely this belongs on serverfault?

Comment: @ILMV: No; this is regarding PHP.

Comment: @ILMV - it's a question about PHP's `mkdir`, so I don't think so.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just tested on gentoo linux with PHP 5.2.12: They all have the same permissions.

```
soulmerge@shark-g:~$ php -a
Interactive shell

php > mkdir('asd/def/ghi', 0700, 1);
php > ^C
soulmerge@shark-g:~$ ls -hal asd
total 12K
drwx------  3 soulmerge soulmerge 4.0K 2010-01-12 10:32 .
drwxr-xr-x 79 soulmerge soulmerge 4.0K 2010-01-12 10:32 ..
drwx------  3 soulmerge soulmerge 4.0K 2010-01-12 10:32 def
```

Comment: That was fast, thanks! Glad PHP is smart enough to do this. =)

Answer (score 4):

The C function responsible for mkdir('localfilesystem', x, true) is php_plain_files_mkdir() in main/streams/plain_wrapper.c. And it calls `php_mkdir(dir, mode TSRMLS_CC);` for the "first" directory it is supposed to create and `VCWD_MKDIR(buf, (mode_t)mode))` for all subdirectories. php_mkdir() does some safe mode checking and then also calls `VCWD_MKDIR`
So yes, the mode parameter is used for all directories created by mkdir(p, x, true).